# Changes not staged for commit git

Tags: git

I'm trying to commit my changes to the `git` but i have this message saying `Changes not staged for commit:`. Before, the command that I always used is `git add-commit -m "message"` but now i don't know what syntax used now in this version of git which is **git version 2.15.0**. I looked for the documentation in the `git` website but no luck. Can someone help me with this?

[image]

Comment: You have to stage changes before committing. Run `git add --all`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Changes not staged for commit" mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134960/what-does-changes-not-staged-for-commit-mean)

Answer (score 4):

Either 1) Use the `-a` flag for auto add:

`git commit -am "your message"`

or 2)

`git add --all`
then 
`git commit -m "Your message"`

Comment: or `git commit -m "message" <file> ...`

Answer (score 1):

Break down the steps to properly understand what is happening inside the hood.

**Step 1:**

```
 ## Add your modified files to stage area using,
 git add -u
```

**Step 2:**

```
 ## Commit/Take snapshot your modified files with message on the staging area
 git commit -m "Add php and bash file payroll"
```

**Step 3:**

```
 ## Push your changes to remote branch using,
 git push
```